# Changing group permission GitLab 7.2 CE

Tags: gitlab

I have just installed GitLab 7.2 CE and try to create a group.  The info says that groups are private by default.  I would like to change the group to public but could not find a way to do this.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only change permission on a per project basis.

If you create a project under a group, you can then changes it's permission by clicking on the project, then settings (top right) and under "Visibility Level" you can choose between Private, Internal and Public.